# Search block in which a given string is enclosed

Tags: search, reverse, forward

All,

I have a text file, say sample.txt.  This file contains many blocks starting and ending with [ and ] respectively.  (Please see attached image).

Now, given a string, say "finance3", is it possible using reverse reg-ex (or something similar) to find the range of lines (i.e. block) which 'holds' the string.

In the [image]example (please see attached image), given string is "finance3" which is in line 18.  The block that has to be returned is: 17-24.

One way of doing it is, get the line number where the string is present and going backwards, grep for line number containing  '['.  Again, start from the line where the string is present and go forward each line, stopping at that line when ']' is encountered.

But, is there a better way to do this using regexps?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Ravi.

Comment: Missed to add: This is to be done in linux, using any of inbuilt tools/sed/awk/python....etc

Answer (score 0):

You can tell awk that records are separated by ], then print the record if it matches your search string:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = "]" } { if (match($0, "finance3")) { print $0 RS } }' sample.txt
```